# Error connecting JAR-wrapper to a SVC-service in BizTalk

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, jar, biztalk

Me and a colleague are trying to get our system to conect to a web service (Microsoft BizTalk).

This is done by a wrapper that is run once every day and could also be run manually.

```
java -jar Person60.jar prod prod_system.jks -v persons.xml
```

When the command is run it throws the follwing error:

```
KeyStore file: /home/paul/prod_system.jks, password: XXXXXXXX
Start: Fri May 22 06:43:38 GMT 2020
Calling : https://tgpstb-prod-lb.i.rugen.de:8181/rs/ip/informationsecurity/authorization/persons/6/GetPersons.svc
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://tgpstb-prod-lb.i.rugen.de:8181/rs/ip/informationsecurity/authorization/person/6/GetPersons.svc
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://tgpstb-prod-lb.i.rugen.de:8181/rs/ip/informationsecurity/authorization/person/6/GetPersons.svc?wsdl

        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:260)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:194)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:163)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
        at de.riv.informationsecurity.authorization.persons.GetPersons.v6.rivtabp21.GetPersonsResponderService.<init>(GetPersonsResponderService.java:39)
        at de.rugen.person60.PersonQuery.getPersons(PersonQuery.java:47)
        at de.rugen.person60.PersonQuery.main(PersonQuery.java:255)
```

Any idea what we got wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you browse to those two URL manually using a browser?

Comment: The first one I get:

"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."

The second one times out.

Comment: There is a problem with your server-side. You need to debug the server-side to get more detailed errors.

Comment: Yeah, that is what we are saying. However the people running the server says everything is fine and that other systems have been able to connect.

Could there be a proprietary dependance? Like that the service needs .NET or something else "M$-only"?

Comment: I've never come across a web service that would have such a proprietary dependency, especially not for a BizTalk service.     Can you use another tool such as Postman to send the payload with the expected method (POST, PUT or PATCH?) headers?   What details have they given you about the web service? e.g. is it SOAP, REST or other?   What authentication scheme is it expecting?